# Excel VBA: Find matching composite keys then compare the rest of the values

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 worksheets and I need to find worksheets A's composite keys under(columns A, B and C) on worksheet B. If they match, I will then proceed on to compare the rest of the values (Eg: columns D-Z). Please note that worksheet B's rows are all jumbled up. This is what I have come up with so far. Somehow I think I am doing it the wrong way when searching for the keys as I cant get the specific row where the matches are. any ideas? Help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Public Sub compare()

Dim RowCount As Long
Dim StartRow As Integer
Dim ColCount As Integer
Dim StartCol As Integer
Dim Key1, Key2, Key3
Dim Target1, Target2, Target3

If Sheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row > Sheets(3).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row Then
RowCount = Sheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Else
RowCount = Sheets(3).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End If

'StartRow
SearchVal = 1
 For Each Cell In Sheets(2).Range("A1:A" & RowCount)
   If Cell.Value = SearchVal Then
    StartRow = Cell.Row
    End If
Next Cell

ColCount = Sheets(2).Cells(StartRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
StartCol = 1


For i = StartRow To RowCount
    If Application.CountA(Rows(i)) <> 0 Then
    Key1 = Sheets(2).Cells(i, 1).Value
    Key2 = Sheets(2).Cells(i, 2).Value
    Key3 = Sheets(2).Cells(i, 3).Value

    Set Target1 = Sheets(3).Columns(1).Find(Key1, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    Set Target2 = Sheets(3).Columns(2).Find(Key2, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    Set Target3 = Sheets(3).Columns(3).Find(Key3, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

    If Not Target1 Is Nothing And Not Target2 Is Nothing And Not Target3 Is Nothing Then
    For j = StartCol To ColCount
   'compare each cell values

    Next j
    End If
    End If
Next i


End Sub
```

Sample excel sheets:

```
Eg:
Worksheet2
------------------------------
|   |  A | B | C |   D   | E |
------------------------------
| 1 | 03 | 5 | C | TextZ | A |
------------------------------
| 2 | 01 | 2 | 4 | TextZ | B |
------------------------------
| 3 | 01 | 2 | 4 | TextZ | C |
------------------------------
| 4 | 22 | T | N | TextZ | D |
------------------------------

Worksheet3
------------------------------
|   |  A | B | C |   D   | E |
------------------------------
| 1 | 01 | 2 | 4 | TextZ | C |
------------------------------
| 2 | 01 | 2 | 4 | TextZ | D |
------------------------------
| 3 | 22 | T | N | TextZ | A |
------------------------------
| 4 | 03 | 5 | C | TextZ | B |
------------------------------
```

EDIT:

```
Public Sub compare()    
Dim sh2 As Worksheet, sh3 As Worksheet
Dim sh2Data As Variant
Dim sh3DataA As Variant 
Dim sh3Data As Variant 
Dim i2 As Long, os3 As Long, i3 As Variant
Dim DoSearch As Boolean 

Set sh2 = Sheets(2)  
Set sh3 = Sheets(3)

With sh2
SearchVal = 1
 For Each Cell In .Range("A1:A" & .Rows.Count)
   If Cell.Value = SearchVal Then
    StartRow = Cell.Row
    End If
Next Cell

    sh2Data = .Range(.[G1], .Cells(.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp)).Resize(, 1)
    sh2Data1 = .Range(.[J1], .Cells(.Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp)).Resize(, 1)
    sh2Data2 = .Range(.[O1], .Cells(.Rows.Count, 15).End(xlUp)).Resize(, 1)

End With

DoSearch = False
For i2 = StartRow To UBound(sh2Data, 1)
With sh3
    sh3Data = .Range(.[G1], .Cells(.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp)).Resize(, 1)
    sh3Data1 = .Range(.[J1], .Cells(.Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp)).Resize(, 1)
    sh3Data2 = .Range(.[O1], .Cells(.Rows.Count, 15).End(xlUp)).Resize(, 1)
End With
os3 = 0
    Do
    i3 = Application.Match(sh2Data(i2, 1), sh3Data, 0)
    If Application.CountA(Rows(i2)) <> 0 Then
        If Not IsError(i3) Then
        ' Col G match
            If (sh2Data1(i2, 1) = sh3Data1(i3, 1)) And (sh2Data2(i2, 1) = sh3Data2(i3, 1)) Then
            ' Match Found Sheet(2) row i2 = Sheet(3) row i3

           MsgBox "Match found sheet2 = " & i2 & ", sheet3 = " & i3 + os3
            End If

          os3 = os3 + i3
          If os3 + i3 < UBound(sh3Data, 1) Then
          With sh3
          sh3Data = .Range(.Cells(i3 + 1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp)).Resize(, 1)
          sh3Data1 = .Range(.Cells(i3 + 1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp)).Resize(, 1)
          sh3Data2 = .Range(.Cells(i3 + 1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 15).End(xlUp)).Resize(, 1)
          End With
          DoSearch = True
          Else
          DoSearch = False
          End If
          Else
          DoSearch = False
        End If
    End If
    Loop Until Not DoSearch
Next i2

End Sub
```

The data tested:

```
Worksheet2
    ------------------------------
    |   | A  | B.. | G.. | J..| O.. |
    ------------------------------
    | 1 | 03 | zxc | 1   | 2  | 3   |
    ------------------------------
    | 2 | 03 | zxc | 1   | 3  | 4   |
    ------------------------------
    | 3 | 03 | zxc | 2   | 2  | 4   |
    ------------------------------
    | 4 | 03 | zxc | 2   | 3  | 4   |
    ------------------------------

Worksheet3

    ------------------------------
    |   | A  | B.. | G.. | J..| O.. |
    ------------------------------
    | 1 | 03 | zxc | 2   | 3  | 4   |
    ------------------------------
    | 2 | 03 | zxc | 2   | 2  | 4   |
    ------------------------------
    | 3 | 03 | zxc | 1   | 3  | 4   |
    ------------------------------
    | 4 | 03 | zxc | 1   | 2  | 3   |
    ------------------------------




So basically
sh2's 1 = sh3's = 4
sh2's 2 = sh3's = 3
sh2's 3 = sh3's = 2
sh2's 4 = sh3's = 1

& the msgbox only shows
sh2's 3 = sh3's = 2
sh2's 4 = sh3's = 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There a are several issues here:

The unqualified references to `Rows` and `Columns` refers to objects on the `ActiveSheet`, For example

```
Sheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

is equivalent to

```
Sheets(2).Cells(Activesheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

You should use

```
    Sheets(2).Cells(Sheets(2).Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

Not sure if this is all the problems (havn't analysed it that closely).  Post back if you are still having problems...

**EDIT**

Based on the data you posted on your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8110633/445425) and your comment, here's a refactor of your code

```
Public Sub compare()
    Dim sh2 As Worksheet, sh3 As Worksheet
    Dim sh2Data As Variant
    Dim sh3DataA As Variant
    Dim sh3Data As Variant
    Dim i2 As Long, i3 As Long

    Set sh2 = Sheets(2)
    Set sh3 = Sheets(3)

    With sh2
        sh2Data = .Range(.[A1], .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Resize(, 3)
    End With
    With sh3            
        sh3DataA = .Range(.[A1], .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Resize(, 1)
        sh3Data = .Range(.[A1], .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Resize(, 3)
    End With

    For i2 = 1 To UBound(sh2Data, 1)
        i3 = Application.Match(sh2Data(i2, 1), sh3DataA, 0)
        If Not IsError(rw) Then
            ' Col A match
            If (sh2Data(i2, 2) = sh3Data(i3, 2)) And (sh2Data(i2, 3) = sh3Data(i3, 3)) Then
                ' Match Found Sheet(2) row i2 = Sheet(3) row i3

            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

This will find the first match in Sheet(3) of each row in Sheet(2).  Do you need to go on and find any further match of the Sheet(2) row?  If so heres another version

```
Public Sub compare()
    Dim sh2 As Worksheet, sh3 As Worksheet
    Dim sh2Data As Variant
    Dim sh3DataA As Variant
    Dim sh3Data As Variant
    Dim i2 As Long, os3 As Long, i3 As Variant
    Dim DoSearch As Boolean

    Set sh2 = Sheets(2)
    Set sh3 = Sheets(3)

    With sh2
        sh2Data = .Range(.[A1], .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Resize(, 3)
    End With

    DoSearch = False
    For i2 = 1 To UBound(sh2Data, 1)
        With sh3
            sh3DataA = .Range(.[A1], .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Resize(, 1)
            sh3Data = .Range(.[A1], .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Resize(, 3)
        End With
        os3 = 0
        Do
            If UBound(sh3Data, 1) > 1 Then
                i3 = Application.Match(sh2Data(i2, 1), sh3DataA, 0)
            Else
                i3 = IIf(sh2Data(i2, 1) = sh3DataA, 1, CVErr(xlErrNA))
            End If
            If Not IsError(i3) Then
                ' Col A match
                If (sh2Data(i2, 2) = sh3Data(i3, 2)) And (sh2Data(i2, 3) = sh3Data(i3, 3)) Then
                    MsgBox "Match found sheet2 = " & i2 & ", sheet3 = " & i3 + os3
                End If
                os3 = os3 + i3
                If os3 < UBound(sh2Data, 1) Then
                    With sh3
                        sh3DataA = .Range(.Cells(i3 + os3, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Resize(, 1)
                        sh3Data = .Range(.Cells(i3 + os3, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Resize(, 3)
                    End With
                    DoSearch = True
                Else
                    DoSearch = False
                End If
            Else
                DoSearch = False
            End If
        Loop Until Not DoSearch
    Next
End Sub
```

By the way, see [This page](http://fastexcel.wordpress.com/) for reason why to use `variant arrays` rather than `Find`

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. However, what I am trying to find out is how to search for the composite keys when the positions of the rows are different in the two worksheets. Later compare the values of the rows with the same composite keys.

Comment: Ok, moving on:  you will need to explain a bit more about your data.  A sample would help.  Specifically what do you mean by *composite keys*? I suspect you mean the cells on a row in sheet 2 from columns A, B and C match the corresponding cells on a single row in sheet 3 (but a different row to sheet 2). Is that right?

Comment: That is right. It is because the key values can appear more than once, that is why I need 3 keys to identify the unique row.

Comment: What if one of my key values is under column E instead of A ?

Comment: Then you will need to adjust the ranges used for the Loop, Match amd/or compare.

Comment: oh, I got it after looking at it longer! Thank you! :D

Comment: Hi Chris, there's another problem when I test out the code. In the msgbox part, it will only display when i2 is larger than i3+os3. Otherwise, nothing. Why is it so?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that: please add another data set sample to your question that cases to problem

Comment: Found a bug in my code.  I have updated my answer with a revised version of the code.

Comment: uhm, somehow it is still not working. So sorry bout it. Im new to vba.

Comment: When I run it it returns sh2 rw1 = sh3 rw3, sh2 rw1 = sh3 rw4, sh2 rw2 = sh3 rw3, sh2 rw2 = sh3 rw4, sh2 rw3 = sh3 rw1, sh2 rw3 = sh3 rw2, sh2 rw4 = sh3 rw1, sh2 rw4 = sh3 rw2.  Is this not what you want?

Comment: No, supposedly it should show 4 messageboxes with sh2's 1 = sh3's = 4 | sh2's 2 = sh3's = 3 | sh2's 3 = sh3's = 2 | sh2's 4 = sh3's = 1

Comment: Your question states after you comapre the composite keys *If they match, I will then proceed on to compare the rest of the values*.  You need to add this additional compare in place of the MsgBox